# Linux benchmark SSD vs HDD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance, ssd, kernel

I wonder if there is any performance difference when using SSD as the main Hard drive rather than mounting it to be used by different applications on the server. For example using a command line program which caches files over the mounted SSD.

In other words: does linux kernel preform faster over SSD than over normal HDD?

OS: CentOS 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel itself doesn't need to access the disk, ever. Except maybe for swap, if configured.

That being said, if you don't start and stop applications on a regular basis (e.g. on a workstation), you won't really benefit from an SSD's speed. To be precise, if we're talking about a server system, you're better off putting regularly accessed files (databases, web hosting files, temporary files, ...) on the SSD.

Comment: Server reboots will be noticeably slower, but Linux is fast anyhow. Rule of thumb: If you load anything use SSD, if you want faster kernel use a faster RAM and CPU. Thus if you have loads of random data fetches then use the ssd. Load the kernel on the HDD, same with programs/files that aren't loaded often (they load once and run 24/7 in RAM).